# Query for items using filter for most recent entry in a related table

Tags: python, html, django, models

Hello I seem be having a problem with querying. I have a list of items. Any Item can have a status set to it (In, out, Collected, Destroyed, etc.). Here is my views.

```
def client_summary(request, client_id):
    client = None
    items = None
try:
    client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
    items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    total_items = items.count()
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('client_summary.html', {'items':items, 'total_items':total_items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

If I have in my template

```
{%for item in items%}
        {{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}
{%endfor%}
```

This will display the all the latest status. Now I want to only to print out all items that their status is Destroyed only. For some reason I can't seem to do this.

Here is some more information from my models as well.

```
class StorageItem(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(StorageObject)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    company_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True, blank = True, null = True)
    content = models.TextField(blank = True)
    alternative_id = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Client no.', max_length = 60, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    format = models.ForeignKey(Format, blank = True, null = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True)
    item_class = models.TextField(blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Status(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    notes = models.TextField(blank = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Status'
        get_latest_by = 'date'
        ordering = ['date']

class ItemStatusHistory(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    item = models.ForeignKey(StorageItem)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.status
```

**EDIT**: There are still some problems because the relation between an item could have many statuses. But I want to only list the most recent status only for destroyed items.

Example: Supposing there are 3 items and they have sets `item1 = [in, out, destroyed]`,  `item2 = [destroyed, in]`, `item3 = [destroyed`, `collected, destroyed]`, `item4 = [in]` where `[1st status, 2nd status, 3rd status, etc]`. I only want to display the latest status for that item.

Both Mike and kriegar will get a result like `[item1, item2, item3, item3]`.
Because Yuji used the distinct function, he will get `[item1, item2, item3]`.

The answer I need to get at the end should be `[item1, item3]`.

Comment: Are you looking for items that *_only_* have destroyed status? Or items that have *any* destroyed status?

Comment: @Yuji sorry for the late reply. You solution is almost correct. However because an Item status can be changed by the user, I only want items to have a _destroyed_ status if this is there _latest status_. So an Item could have a destroyed status one week, but have it's status changed by the user to collected. Once it has its status changed. It should not be in the _destroyed_ status list. What your code does is says looks in any item to see if it has a _destroyed_ status. Then print. It should only print if _destroyed_ is latest status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kriegar's solution will work.  There's also this one, which searches by Status `id` instead of text matching on `description`:

```
destroyedStatus = Status.objects.get(description="destroyed")
clients_destroyed_items = StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client, 
    itemstatushistory__status=destroyedStatus)
```

This assumes descriptions are unique, but you have no such constraint in your model. I have no idea which implementation is faster.

**EDIT:** By the way, if you've got some crazy system where you have more than one Status with a description of "destroyed", and you wanted to query by Status `id`s instead of `description`, you would just do:

```
destroyedStatusIDs = Status.objects.filter(description="destroyed").values_list("id", flat=True)
clients_destroyed_items = StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client, 
    itemstatushistory__status__in=destroyedStatusIDs)
```

BTW, it's considered good practice to set `related_name` on your `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, and `ManyToManyField` relationships, usually to plurals.  So your history class becomes:

```
class ItemStatusHistory(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="history")
    item = models.ForeignKey(StorageItem, related_name="history")
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name="history")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="history")
```

which would change my first example to:

```
destroyedStatus = Status.objects.get(description="destroyed")
clients_destroyed_items = StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client, 
    history__status=destroyedStatus)
```

**EDIT 2:** Ah, so you only want to consider the current (i.e. latest) Status. This is where  [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/) and [F objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) come in.  Basically, the idea is to have the database create a "fake column" in the table which has the `date` of the latest (i.e. maximum `date`) Status, then require the date to match as well as the status:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

destroyedStatus = Status.objects.get(description="destroyed")
clients_destroyed_items = StorageItem.objects.annotate(
    last_change_date=Max("itemstatushistory__date")).filter(client=client, 
    itemstatushistory__status=destroyedStatus, 
    itemstatushistory__date=F("last_change_date"))
```

I haven't tested this, this is the first time I've tried this, and there may be a better way, so comments are welcome.

Comment: I've always been using related_name as well because i like explict over implict.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error message `'Status' object has no attribute 'values_list'`

Comment: Whoops, forgot to change `get` to `filter`.  Fixed.

Comment: Hmm, seem to get Database errors. `Caught OperationalError while rendering: (1054, "Unknown column 'T6.date' in 'having clause'")`

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas.  You may have to denormalize your database some by putting `status = models.ForeignKey(Status)` into `StorageItem` and then using that field to store an item's current status, in which case your query is something like `Status.objects.get(description="destroyed").storageitem_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a queryset of the items that belong to a client and are destroyed:

```
clients_destroyed_items = StorageItem.objects.filter(client=client, 
    itemstatushistory__status__description='destroyed')
```

> Lookups that span relationships¶
>
> Django offers a powerful and intuitive
>   way to "follow" relationships in
>   lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs
>   for you automatically, behind the
>   scenes. To span a relationship, just
>   use the field name of related fields
>   across models, separated by double
>   underscores, until you get to the
>   field you want.
>
> This example retrieves all Entry
>   objects with a Blog whose name is
>   'Beatles Blog':
>
> > > > Entry.objects.filter(blog_*name*_exact='Beatles
> > > >         Blog')
>
> This spanning can be as deep as you'd
>   like.
>
> **It works backwards, too. To refer to a
>   "reverse" relationship, just use the
>   lowercase name of the model.**

Comment: or `client.storageitem_set.filter(itemstatushistory__status__description='Destroyed').distinct()` and by the way when `related_name` is not set, the default query field name doesn't include the `_set`, so it's just `itemstatushistory__status__description`

Comment: "by the way when related_name is not set, the default query field name doesn't include the _set, so it's just itemstatushistory__status__description" ... That is contradicted by the documentation: ["If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased."](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: I really shouldn't answer questions when im tired. =)

Comment: @Mike those are instance managers. I'm not sure if I've seen documentation for the field names. I haven't looked to be honest! Try messing around with a model where you don't specify `related_name`. Instances will have a FOO_set manager, lookups with FOO_set as a field wil fail.

Comment: Three cheers for naming inconsistency.  Maybe in some future version they'll get rid of this "_set" nonsense, since it's apparently not needed to avoid name clashes. Fixed my answer.